# Jquery: variable assignment

Tags: jquery

I trying to get the property of input element with value of 7. Here I assigned 7 to paypalid and then using that variable in getting the value of the property. But when I see the source in the browser paypalid is not replaced with 7. I think I am doing something wrong.

```
<script>
   var paypalid="7";
   var checked=$("input[value=" + paypalid + "]").prop("checked");
</script>
```

Comment: Because the values will be evaluated in runtime....

Comment: Are you trying to see the state checkbox with `value=7`?

Comment: which browser you are using? try it var checked=$('input[value="' + paypalid + '"]').prop("checked");

Comment: @miguelmpn yes. Is it possible?

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan You won't be able to see the change in the source code, but it should work. What does your HTML look like? Are you checking `checked`? If you use `console.log(paypalid, checked)` and check your console, what does it say?

Comment: Use `$('input[value=7]').prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Please check my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q5kzyek3/1/)

This is the code I'm using

```
<body>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="7" checked>I have a 7 cars 
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="9">I don't have 9 cars 
</form>

</body>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var paypalid="7";
  var checked=$("input[value=" + paypalid + "]").prop("checked");
  alert(checked);

  paypalid="9";
  checked=$("input[value=" + paypalid + "]").prop("checked");
  alert(checked);
});
```